# FillRect Wont draw to the screen

Tags: c++, winapi

Im doing a tetris clone to learn how the WinApi works:

```
const int sm = 30, //screen multiplier
fWidth = 12, fHeight = 20;

char field[fHeight][fWidth];

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        for (int y = 0; y < fHeight; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < fWidth; x++)
            {
                bool i;
                HBRUSH brush;
                RECT rect = { (x + 1) * sm, y * sm, (x + 2) * sm, (y + 1) * sm };
                switch (field[y][x])
                {
                case 'x':
                    brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
                    break;
                default:
                    brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
                    break;
                }
                FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
                DeleteObject(brush);
            }

        
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI GameLoop(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HWND hwnd = *reinterpret_cast<HWND*>(lpParam);
    MSG msg;
    msg.hwnd = hwnd;
    msg.message = WM_PAINT;
    while (!quit)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                if (tetriminous[tetrimino][x + 4 * y] == 'x')
                    field[pieceY + y][pieceX + x] = ' ';

        pieceY += 1;

        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                if (tetriminous[tetrimino][x + 4 * y] == 'x')
                    field[pieceY + y][pieceX + x] = 'x';

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        Sleep(300);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use the gameloop as a thread and dispatch WM_PAINT after updates.
the problem is that in VM_PAINT section, the fillRect doesnt draw to the screen. I debagged and the rect is on the screen. also the fillrect returns a success code. what is the problem?

Comment: IIRC you don't draw by dispatching WM_PAINT, but by calling `InvalidateRect`. I think there's no drawing because Windows considers the window already updated. Use `InvalidateRect` to fix that. (However it's been literally decades since I last did any of this stuff).

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing then using a multithreaded GUI is going to fail. Inevitably. Leaking your brushes certainly won't help either. Regardless, we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: You are leaking brush handles，please put them outside the loop and delete them in time.  But this is not enough to solve your problem, at least we can't reproduce it from the code you provided.

Comment: @joh You absolutely *do* render window contents by handling `WM_PAINT`. The job of `InvalidateRect` is to mark part or all of a window's client rectangle as invalid which will eventually cause the system to generate a `WM_PAINT` message. There's `RedrawWindow` for the rare case when you need to immediately repaint a window. That's still going to get handled by `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: @IInspectable I realise that and I may have misunderstood the OP. They said 'dispatching' and I read that as 'sending' but you're right, they may well have just meant that they are handling WM_PAINT messages.

Comment: WM_PAINT is a special message that gets triggered by InvalidateRect (and others). Do not use Post- or SendMessage. You also need to retrieve the message from the queue. See 'Paint messages will come in as fast as you let them' (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111219-00/?p=8863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was fixed after changing the DispatchMessage to InvalidateRect.